# If I have IDEA, do I need rubymine for ruby dev or will it do both?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

Does IDEA support all the features of rubymine, or is rubymine more refined for rails and IDEA doesn't have all the rubymine features?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Ruby plugin does include all the features of RubyMine, although the latest version of the Ruby plugin usually requires EAP builds of IntelliJ IDEA. (At the moment, the version of the Ruby plugin for IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.3 does not include all of the new features of RubyMine 2.5 - only the version of the plugin for IntelliJ IDEA X EAP does.)

RubyMine also has a simplified project configuration UI that works better for Rails projects.

Comment: and is jruby a different plugin?

Comment: i see, so IDEA is always a little behind the latest version of rubymine, i get it.

Comment: JRuby support is part of the Ruby plugin.