# What are the big differences between IntelliJ + Ruby Plugin vs RubyMine?

Tags: ruby, ide, intellij-idea, rubymine

Being an owner of IntelliJ Idea Ultimate edition, and having installed the IntelliJ Ruby plug-in, I'm forced to wonder how different that experience is from using the RubyMine IDE.

I'm guessing they share a lot of code & features. What are the major differences?

If I'm jumping into the world of Ruby, should I buy the RubyMine IDE or just continue using IntelliJ + Ruby plug-in?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Ruby plugin and RubyMine are build from the same codebase, that's right.

Java/Ruby integration for JRuby code is only available in Ruby plugin for IntelliJ IDEA. But the plugin doesn't have RubyMotion support.

Also check this answer: [If I have IDEA, do I need rubymine for ruby dev or will it do both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768593/if-i-have-idea-do-i-need-rubymine-for-ruby-dev-or-will-it-do-both)

Comment: That page does not indicate the difference anymore. That is why you are asked to provide a complete response here even when you provide a complementary link. Anyways, this question is a duplicate. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827214/can-intellij-idea-encapsulate-all-of-the-functionality-of-webstorm-and-phpstorm